# Vue 3: Cannot create property 'x' on <type> 'y'

Tags: vuejs3

This is so annoying and I don't know how to solve this.

I am using Vue 3 refs in external class:

[image]

I am changing the value as it supposed to be changed using .value:

[image]

But I get an error:

```
Cannot create property 'value' on boolean 'false'
```

I understand that refs are automatically unwrapped to shallow refs if they were returned from setup() function, but this is clearly not the case.

Comment: is this from the same component or are you passing the ref?

Comment: @Daniel It's not even a component, it's just a class, and I didn't pass this value anywhere, I just change the value in class methods like I show in question :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and resolved it by not making the property a Ref object.

i.e. Rather than

```
dragging = ref(false);
```

Using:

```
dragging = false;
```

Reactivity in components using the class worked fine.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but will check it again, thanks :(